# Change IntelliJ Console WARNING or ERROR message color

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration

I've been trying to change my IntelliJ Console color on WARNING and ERROR messages because it  has a **yellow background color** that looks like this:

[image: Console WARNING message]

I've tried to change this under **Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Console Colors** but none of the settings appear to change this.

Here is a snapshot of my current settings
[image: Console Colors settings]

As you may see, there is none with a yellow background like the previous image.

Changing console font size on those settings changes the size indeed so the setting should be there

I'm using Darcula theme and have already tried to restore everything to default but it ain't working.

I haven't found any information about this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Configure this in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Editor | **Selection background** setting:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying, however I had already watched those settings, in my case i have a blue background in "Selection background" and it's not really when i select a thing, the yellow color is due to WARNING or ERROR messages only.